# Javascript: Detect colliding divs

Tags: javascript, html, geometry, collision-detection, algebra

How do I detect if two divs are overlapping?

Not taking into consideration the width of a div, it is basically a vertical line segment. The (top,left) point is point A while the bottom (top + height) is point B and so forth. I'd then compare each div to each to the other divs in the divs array and then create an array of colliding divs. However, I'm stuck on how to do this programmatically.

This is my array of divs:

```
var divs = [
    {class:'A', top:0,   left:0,   height:'60px'},
    {class:'B', top:50,  left:60,  height:'60px'},
    {class:'C', top:30,  left:10,  height:'60px'},
    {class:'D', top:100, left:180, height:'60px'},
    {class:'E', top:80,  left:50,  height:'60px'},
    {class:'F', top:110, left:200, height:'60px'},
    {class:'G', top:55,  left:80,  height:'60px'}
];
```

Here's the function I had started:

```
    this.collide = function( divs )
{
    var collidingDivs = [], z = events.length;

    for(i; i<z; i++)
    {
        if
        (
           // Begin pseudocode
           ( divsB.top >= divsA.top ) && 
           ( (divsB.top + divsB.height) <= (divsA.top + divsA.height) ) 
        )
        {
            collidingDivs.push(divs[i].class);
        }
    }
    console.log(collidingDivs); // Array of divs that overlap (collide)
};
```

I'm just utterly stuck at this point. How do I iterate over each div and check if it collides with any of the other divs?

Comment: Don't you also need a `width` for each div??

Comment: At first I thought about using a point-in-polygon type of deal. 

However, I then realized that all I really need to know is whether the top and bottom points of a div overlap with any other top/bottom points from other divs in the array.

Honestly, it doesn't matter how I get the results. I just need to figure out which divs overlap with the other divs in the array and then scoot them over so they don't overlap. 

I've spent a day working on this and for some reason I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through each div, and then compare with every other div in a nested loop.  Then use logic like what you've written to compare each combination.  Here is an example that simply prints out the overlapping divs to the output (note also that I changed the `height` element to have a numerical value rather than text so that its value could be used in calculations):

```
var divs = [
    {class:'A', top:0,   left:0,   height:60},
    {class:'B', top:50,  left:60,  height:60},
    {class:'C', top:30,  left:10,  height:60},
    {class:'D', top:100, left:180, height:60},
    {class:'E', top:80,  left:50,  height:60},
    {class:'F', top:110, left:200, height:60},
    {class:'G', top:55,  left:80,  height:60}
];

for (var i=0; i < divs.length - 1; i++)
    for (var j=i+1; j < divs.length; j++)
    {
        var I=divs[i];
        var J=divs[j];

        if ( (I.top <= J.top && (I.top + I.height) >= J.top) ||
             (J.top <= I.top && (J.top + J.height) >= I.top) )
            document.writeln(
                I.class + " collides with " + J.class + "<br />");
    }
```

Output:

```
A collides with B
A collides with C
A collides with G
B collides with C
B collides with D
B collides with E
B collides with F
B collides with G
C collides with E
C collides with G
D collides with E
D collides with F
D collides with G
E collides with F
E collides with G
F collides with G
```

Sample working code: http://jsfiddle.net/QUrWM/

Comment: This is brilliant! Exactly what I was attempting to do. Thank you!!

Comment: How do I set divs that collide with each other to an array? For example, class A collides with three other divs. How do I set those three particular divs to an array? How do I count them?

Something along the lines of this?:
`code`
      var divArray = [];
  for(i; i<l; i++){
      divArray.push(arrX.id);
  }
`code`


...and to count would just be 
`code` 
var total = divArray.length;
`code`

?

Comment: You can easily dump the results into an array by simply adding `I.class` and `J.class` to an array.  The bigger question is what exactly are you trying to accomplish with these results?

Comment: ugh, how do I format code in a comment??

Anyhow, yes, I tried that but didn't output anything. Unless I'm placing in the wrong location. I'll attempt again.

I'll share the final results once I get it all worked out :)

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to determine which divs are overlapping. Those that are overlapping, I need to shift to the right. That way, the divs don't overlap anymore.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that wasn't the answer you wanted. What I am trying to find out is how many events collide and which events collide with other events. I will then divide the width of each event so they're evenly distributed within the main container of the divs.
Does that help give an idea of what I'm doing? I just don't want divs to overlap each other visually.

Comment: You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QUrWM/5/.  I have stored an additional array `collidesWith` in each `div` object, which I populate with a collection of div classes that collide.  I then print out the list and the count for each div.  See what you can build off of that.

Comment: Ok, I've created about three or four different versions using various combinations of for loops, etc and I think I've narrowed it down to the most optimized version yet. However, I'm now stuck on shifting the colliding divs. Probably simple math/logic equation I'm missing. Can you take a look at what I have so far? http://jsfiddle.net/Sj3TP/1/

Comment: Divs 1-3 collide so they should be evenly distributed within the main container (width:400px). The left positions for each of the three should be offset by the amount of their widths. Divs 6-7 are waaay off to the right.
Everything works fine for the first three but the logic is screwy as you go further and further. More than likely I'm not using the correct iterator OR I'm missing another for loop somewhere.

Comment: Maybe something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/Sj3TP/2/.  I made quite a few changes - I didn't quite understand your `g` for loop.  I added a `placed` option to each div to detect whether it has already been adjusted.  If not, then it loops through the set {me, my collisions), and for each one, sets position beside each other, and marks them all as placed.  I also converted your `display` div into a logging area at the bottom.  The changes I made should also address the situation where the divs that are in collision don't necessarily have to be in order.

Comment: this is brilliant!!! I've been working with this code and made a few of mods by incorporating it into a class structure, etc. Thank you for your assistance!